# Cant insert records with null value (sql)?

Tags: sql

`"insert into [Table2] ([Code], [#]) select [Code], [#] from Table1 "`

That sql code works fine at first, but it won't add records if either Code or # has null value. How do I work around this? I'm working in VB.Net, if that's any help.

Comment: Please show the VB code you're using, and tell us what *does* happen if the value is null. Do you really have a column called `#` by the way? That sounds like a bad idea, even if it works.

Comment: Are the columns defined as `not null`?

Comment: Blorgbeard is right. This is almost certainly a column definition involving "NOT NULL"

Answer (score 0):

If the column you are trying to insert into is defined as "NOT NULL" then you cannot insert a null value into it.

To get around this you can check if the value is NULL prior to inserting, and depending on your column's datatype set the value to an empty string ('') or 0 or some other value that MAKES SENSE for your purposes.